# Filtering in Python

Tags: python, data-analysis

I am new in Python sorry if my question doesn't suit here.

I have a large datasets related to Airbnb. There is a column called city which has main cities in the USA: 1- NYC 2-Chicago, And Los Angelos

I want to do the analysis only in NYC. Here is my method so far

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd 


Airbnb = pd.read_csv("file location")

Airbnb_NYC = Airbnb["city" == " NYC"]
```

I tried to list the rest of the columns with there data but no luck

Airbnb.shape

```
74111,29
```

Comment: We'd need some [Minimal Reproducible Example (MRE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to help you. But As first read I suggest https://www.w3schools.com/python/

Comment: `"city" == " NYC"` evaluates as `False`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Airbnb_NYC = Airbnb[Airbnb["city"] == " NYC"]
```

(And check if you mean " NYC" or "NYC" ;-) )

Answer (score 0):

The answer is this:

```
Airbnb_NYC = Airbnb[(Airbnb.city== "NYC")]
```

it works!